# How do you only execute if the promise was fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm using promises to force NodeJS to stop running if certain functions do not execute as required. At the moment, the server stops as required but I would also like to include a console log if the functions successfully fulfilled their promises. I'm using the npm 'q' module.

Working code

```
Q.all([
    someFunction1(),
    someOtherFunction('https://www.google.com', 'Google'),
    someOtherFunction('https://www.facebook.com', 'Facebook'),
])
    .catch(function (err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
})
```

When adding a then as per below, the then executes before the promises has been completed and therefore the console.log call is executed regardless of whether the promise is fulfilled or rejected.

```
Q.all([
    someFunction1(),
    someOtherFunction('https://www.google.com', 'Google'),
    someOtherFunction('https://www.facebook.com', 'Facebook'),
])
    .then(console.log("No problem here"))
    .catch(function (err){
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
})
```

Comment: Are you returning promises from your functions? If a non-promise value is returned from the functions contained in the .all[], it will evaluate immediately

Comment: I did have promises returned - but that is a useful point to remember - thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `console.log` in-place, so it is invoked regardless of whether the promise succeeds or fails.

Pass a function to `.then` that contains the log as a statement, and this only will be invoked on success of `Q.all(...)`:

```
.then(function () {
    console.log("No problem here");
})
```